# Exporting same attribute values to separate layers and merging them in QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector-layer, watershed

I am trying to split watersheds of the same attribute table into separate layers.

[image: Attribute table is like this.]

The Two two repeated values, for eg. SW1 and SW1 both are splits from a same watershed called 'SW1'. I am trying to achieve a single layer with both SW1 and SW2 without getting dissolved. So that I can run calculations for both of the them for my purpose.

By visually I am trying to achieve like this

**Original visualization**
[image]

**The repeated labels of SW1 has came together as a single layer**
[image]

How to do this automatically without selecting each of them?

Comment: Duplicate the layer. Set up a query on one copy for Bank=RB, and Bank=Null for the other.

Comment: I want to extract layers SW1(SW1&SW1), SW2(SW2&SW2)....SW16(SW16&SW16) in one go

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look into **Split Vector Layer** in QGIS's Processing Toolbox. You can use a field to split an existing layer into layers containing unique values of that field.

Comment: I have updated my question again. Split layer can be used to select RB and non RB

Comment: Split on Sub_Waters instead

Comment: It worked now! thanks

Comment: There are many useful processing tools. Take some time to look at the Processing menu and explore them.

Comment: Got it..! Qgis is awesome